# Defining fallback behavior on exception for a ContentEnricher in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I've got a nice flow defined with Spring Integration, in the nominal case it works just as I want it to.

However I haven't figured out a way yet to define behavior to handle the error (i.e. marking the input row as failed)

Here's the error I get:

```
 [ask-scheduler-2] cMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel : Reply message received but the receiving thread has exited due to an exception while sending the request message:ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [outboundGateway]; nested exception is...
```

Here's my flow configuration (simplified):

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfig {


    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mainFlow() {
        //noinspection unchecked
        return IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource(),
                c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(5000)
                        .transactional(transactionManager())))
                .split()
                .enrich(e -> e
                        .requestChannel(subChannel())
                        .requestPayload(Message::getPayload)
                        .propertyExpression("fooId", "payload.id"))
                .handle(barHandler())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow enricherFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(subChannel())
                .handle(outboundGateway())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel subChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource<Object> jdbcMessageSource() {
        return new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(this.dataSource,
                "select * from FOO");
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcOutboundGateway outboundGateway() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcMessageHandler barHandler() {
        return new JdbcMessageHandler(dataSource,
                "INSERT INTO BAR ...");
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }
}
```

I would have thought I could get errors on the default errorChannel and perform the necessary tasks there, but I haven't found  way to make this work.

Any ideas and help are highly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know looks like we have missed to expose `errorChannel` for the `EnricherSpec` in Java DSL - feel free to raise a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) on the matter. But anyway that looks like we can get access to that property:

```
.enrich(e -> {
            ContentEnricher contentEnricher =
                    e.requestChannel(subChannel())
                            .requestPayload(Message::getPayload)
                            .propertyExpression("fooId", "payload.id"))
                            .get().getT2();
            contentEnricher.setErrorChannel(enricherErrorChannel());
        })
```

Now you can add any `.handle()` flow to that `enricherErrorChannel()` and process an `ErrorMessage` as you fish. For example typically that `ErrorMessage` contains a `payload` as `MessagingException` where we have a `failedMessage` property. And exactly that one contains an information about your original `payload` and `headers` as well:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler

Comment: I figured it out at the same time, thanks, and here you are : https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4383 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/2335